# Grabbing Information from API using python

Tags: python, api

I am working on a program that will grab information from a Crypto Exchange.  I have been successful at grabbing the information and displaying the first record, however i cannot grab the subsequent records.

Here is the code i am using, the print statement is merely to show i can grab the correct information for 1 record, but it will be great to work my way through the whole set.

```
url = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetCurrencies"
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))

coin_Id = data["Data"][0]["Id"]
coin_Name = data["Data"][0]["Name"]
coin_Symbol = data["Data"][0]["Symbol"]
coin_Algorithm = data["Data"][0]["Algorithm"]
coin_withdrawfee = data["Data"][0]["WithdrawFee"]
coin_MinBaseTrade = data["Data"][0]["MinBaseTrade"]
coin_IsTipEnabled = data["Data"][0]["IsTipEnabled"]
coin_MinTip = data["Data"][0]["MinTip"]
coin_DepositConfirmations = data["Data"][0]["DepositConfirmations"]
coin_Status = data["Data"][0]["Status"]
coin_StatusMessage = data["Data"][0]["StatusMessage"]
coin_ListingStatus = data["Data"][0]["ListingStatus"]


print "ID: " + str(coin_Id) + "\n" + "Name: " + str(coin_Name) + "Symbol: " + str(coin_Symbol) + "\n" + "Status: " + str(coin_Status) + "\n" + "Status Message: " + str(coin_StatusMessage)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **iterate over your result**:

**Ex:**

```
import urllib2
import json
url = "https://www.cryptopia.co.nz/api/GetCurrencies"
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(url))
print data
for d in data["Data"]:
    print d["Id"], d["Name"], d["Symbol"], d["Algorithm"], d["WithdrawFee"]
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Updated

I believe what you want to do is loop through the contents of the data you retrieved and stored in the variable `data`. Given the code you provided in your question, you could do something like:

```
# Assumes 'url' and 'data' exist per the code sample in your question
for row in data:
    coin_Id = row["Id"]
    coin_Name = row["Name"]
    coin_Symbol = row["Symbol"]
    # ...
    coin_Status = row["Status"]
    coin_StatusMessage = row["StatusMessage"]
    coin_ListingStatus = row["ListingStatus"]

    # Assumes you grabbed values for all of the keys
    print "ID: " + str(coin_Id) + "\n" + "Name: " + str(coin_Name) + "Symbol: " + str(coin_Symbol) + "\n" + "Status: " + str(coin_Status) + "\n" + "Status Message: " + str(coin_StatusMessage)
```

Comment: Thank you Keith.  I tried your solution, but it still gave me the 1st record only information without any Loop.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Oops! I just realized I typed up my solution wrong. Sorry about that. I fixed it for the record.